# If $X\subset \mathbb{R}$ is bounded and a infinity set, then $X \cap X^\prime \not = \emptyset$.

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

First of all, let us define $X^\prime = \{a \in \mathbb{R} \mid \forall\epsilon>0, ((a - \epsilon, a + \epsilon)-\{a\}) \cap X \not = \emptyset\}$. The result is true when $X$ is an uncountable set: if $X \cap X^\prime = \emptyset$, then for all $x \in X$ there is an $\epsilon_x>0$ such that $((x - \epsilon_x, x + \epsilon_x)-\{x\}) \cap X = \emptyset$. It implies that all points of $X$ are isolated points. Then, $X$ should be a countable set (a contradition). So, $X \cap X^\prime \not = \emptyset$.

But, what happens when $X$ is a countable set?

Comment: Your definition of $X'$ contains an undeciperhable $a$.

Comment: I'm sorry, typing error.. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $X = \left\{\frac{1}{n} : n \in \Bbb N\right\}.$ Then, $X' = \{0\}$ and $X \cap X' = \varnothing$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Sometimes the answers are simples hahaha :)

Comment: Indeed :-) I was surprised that no one had pointed this so far!